# How to check when a coldfusion flash form is finished loading

Tags: flash, actionscript, coldfusion

I am working on a project that uses Coldfusion flash forms and actionscript. 
When the form is loaded, there is onLoad functionality that is executed.

This functionality does a bunch of calls that query the database and that then update fields on the form.

What I would like to do, ONLY once the form has been populated and finishing setting all the fields, is call another function that uses values that were set in the onLoad functionality.

So for example, using comments to illustrate the processing order, this is what does NOT work:

```
//onLoad() function
SetA(); //sets a form field called A by querying the database and updating A
SetB(); //sets a form field called B by querying the database and updating B
SetC(); //sets a form field called C by querying the database and updating C
DoSomethingWithABC(); // Uses the values A,B,C
```

The problem is that when DoSomethingWithABC() is called, the queries have not yet completed and thus the values of A,B and C have not yet been set, causing the DoSomethingWithABC() method to error.

So, the only way I can think to combat this, is to call an event that fires when the form is actually finished loading all the data, maybe something like OnLoaded() or similar.

Does anyone know of such events? Or, if there aren't any, how would I get around this type of issue? It's really driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Comment: Flash forms suck. I feel for you having to deal with this. My first recommendation would be to rewrite the form using HTML. However, it is possible that you cannot do that. I think this, http://www.asfusion.com/blog/entry/onload-event-coldfusion-flash-forms-1, may help you get at least staretd down the path you are looking. No guarantees, though.

Comment: Having recently disagreed with @ScottStroz, I thought it worth mentioning that I share his opinion on the topic of flash forms.

Comment: @ScottStroz: Yeah thanks for the link. I actually tried that before posting here, but no luck. :/

Comment: @Cheeky - Can you post a simplified version of what you tried? If you post an example we can test independently, maybe someone can spot the problem.

Comment: @Leigh: The example there is as simple as I can post. If I have to expand it further based on what we've done, it would be too much code and require a link to a database as part of the problem is the tie it takes for queries to execute and return data and populate the fields on the form. If I could post a small, simplified example, I would.

Comment: @Cheeky - Yeah, I realize it cannot be a complete "standalone" example, but it has been a while since most people used flash forms. So even posting a simplified example with two shell functions might encourage others to give it a whirl. It is up to you though.